# Affymetrix Custom CDF segmentation fault

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm using the following CDF file for the Affymetrix chip of Brachypodium dystachion. Apparently, it follows all the rules of the [Affymetrix CDF specification](http://www.affymetrix.com/support/developer/powertools/changelog/gcos-agcc/cdf.html)

http://giorgilab.org/BradiGiorgiMutwil001_txt.cdf

However, when I try to create a customcdf environment out of it, using R and the Bioconductor package *makecdfenv*

> library(makecdfenv)
>   make.cdf.package("BradiGiorgiMutwil001_txt.cdf",species="Brachypodium_dystachion")

I get the following error:

> Reading CDF file.
>
> *** caught segfault *** address 0x1, cause 'memory not mapped'
>
> Traceback:  1: .Call("readCDFfile", as.character(file), as.integer(3),
>   as.integer(compress),     PACKAGE = "makecdfenv")  2:
>   read.cdffile(file.path(path.expand(cdf.path), filename), compress =
>   compress)  3: make.cdf.env(filename, cdf.path = cdf.path, compress =
>   compress,     return.env.only = FALSE)  4:
>   make.cdf.package("BradiGiorgiMutwil001_txt.cdf", species =
>   "Brachypodium_dystachion")

Is there anything that strikes you as wrong in the input CDF file? I'm totally puzzled, because I don't know how to interprete this segmentation fault, nor how to trace it to a specific problem. Something similar happens while using the *affxparser* Bioconductor package, so it must be a problem with the CDF fields (and not with the package).

Thanks a lot! :-)

Federico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function make.cdf.package() does **not** require a binary cdf, so there is no reason to have a test.

I took a look at this yesterday, and there isn't anything obviously wrong with this cdf, so it's nice that simply converting to binary fixes things.

Answer (score 3):

The function `make.cdf.package()` work only on binary cdf. You need to convert your cdf with `affxparser::convertCdf()` then you can create the package.

Comment: it is interesting that this causes a segfault though.  Even though it is "operator error", it might be worth contacting the package maintainer to have them add a test that would check for this and stop more gracefully/issue a meaningful error message ...

Comment: It worked like a charm! However, as James said, make.cdf.package() does not require a binary cdf, so the nature of this bug still puzzles me. I just notified the authors on the customcdf mailing list. For now, thanks a lot!